# jQuery datetimepicker default time is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery datetimepicker. I used minDate to set the minimum date, a user can select.  Now i want to make timepicker independent. So I am using hour and minute to set the default time, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
       minDate: "06/20/2017",
       hour : '06',
       minute: '00'
});
```

It give me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: option hour is not recognized!

Comment: The answer is in the question. Option hour is not recognized.

Comment: so what to use, or how to do this with any other method?

Comment: How about initialize with this`$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({format: 'HH:mm'});` and then set the value as `$("#datetimepicker1").val("18:56:00");`

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, let me know if there is any problem:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
       minDate: "06/20/2017"
});
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setHours(6);
myDate.setMinutes(0);
myDate.setDate(20);
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker("setDate", myDate);
```